# C Wrapper of OpenCV's inRange?

Tags: c++, c, opencv, wrapper

I'm writing a C wrapper for OpenCV's C++ inRange.  The wrapper is below.

```
 void cv_inRange(InputArray* src, InputArray* lowerb, InputArray* upperb, OutputArray* dst) {
     cv::inRange(*src, *lowerb, *upperb, *dst);
 }
```

When I run it I get this error using g++ on ubuntu - the compile command works for everything else

```
error: cannot declare pointer to ‘cv::InputArray {aka const class cv::_InputArray&}’
```

I know I can make 2 separate wrappers as below and get the functionality inRange is supposed to have

```
 void cv_inRange(Mat* src, Mat* lowerb, Mat* upperb, Mat* dst) {
     cv::inRange(*src, *lowerb, *upperb, *dst);
 }
 void cv_inRangeS(Mat* src, Scalar* lowerb, Scalar* upperb, Mat* dst) {
     cv::inRange(*src, *lowerb, *upperb, *dst);
 }
```

but in the documentation for InputArray it says:

"This is the proxy class for passing read-only input arrays into OpenCV functions. It is defined as

`typedef const _InputArray& InputArray;`

where `_InputArray` is a class that can be constructed from `Mat, Mat_<T>, Matx<T, m, n>, std::vector<T>, std::vector<std::vector<T> > or std::vector<Mat>`. It can also be constructed from a matrix expression."

and I would like to pass any one of the above types into my C wrapper for inRange,  but making a pointer to InputArray is not working.  If someone can help me write a C wrapper that would be able to include all types as stated above,  I would appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: just use a Mat* instead of InputArray* . the deref'ed Mat will be converted automatically inside of inRange

Comment: A C wrapper or a C++ wrapper? Thats not clear in the question. Given that code/info, I think you are talking about C++ wrapper and you should remove the C tags/terms at all.

Comment: @berak when I  use Mat* in place of InputArray and try to feed it a scalar i.e.  new Scalar(160,170,60) for the upperb and lowerb parameters. I get the below error


`cannot convert ‘cv::Scalar* {aka cv::Scalar_<double>*}’ to ‘cv::Mat*’`

Comment: "when i use" - means what ?

Comment: @berak accidentally hit enter before I was done ..sorry about that:)

Comment: @Manu343726 Thanks for getting to me so soon, it is a C wrapper around C++ code that's why I used those tags:)... sorry for the confusion

Comment: ah, right. so either ignore my idea, or you'll have to come up with a separate function, that uses scalars (known problem in c, you can't 'overload' functions)

Comment: @berak I didn't ignore your idea I used this as you suggested `void cv_inRange(Mat* src, Mat* lowerb, Mat* upperb, Mat* dst)`

but got the error I stated in a previous comment `cannot convert ‘cv::Scalar* {aka cv::Scalar_<double>*}’ to ‘cv::Mat*` forgot to say Thank you for getting to me so soon:)